# can't start the adt-bunlde on ubuntu to run a program

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

i have recently changed back to Ubuntu from windows and i am trying to start android programming on it again. i have installed oracle Jdk and downloaded the bundle but when I open it it gives me the error:

> [2014-03-07 13:45:03 - adb] Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program
>   "/home/abdollah/Documents/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb":
>   error=2, No such file or directory' while attempting to get adb
>   version from
>   '/home/abdollah/Documents/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb'

could it be because i had CDT before separately with a different version of eclipse before? with the same work-space? would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can recheck that, your ubuntu os is 64 bit and ADT is 64 bit.

Comment: the command that u have given is not working on ubuntu 13.10 i have googled a bit and found this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182653 but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be you changed the directory of the adt-bundle from where you unpacked it,
try unpacking it to the desired location again.

Basically your installation doesn't find adb any more, try to check /home/abdollah/Documents/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb and post wether it exist or not

Comment: yeah it does exist! but let unpack it again and tell you

Comment: Otherwise if you can open adt but can't run any program try to edit your sdk location in Windows/Preference/Android/SDK Loaction

Comment: yes it does open but can't run any programss! let me do as you said .

Answer (score 0):

Source :https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

May be you will need lib apt-get  ia32-libs

Comment: avoid one line answers, also avoid links. post the content of the link because in future corresponding link may not work

Comment: @RafayZiaMir thank you .I will surely keep in mind from next time